# How to get a vuetify data table to span the entire width of a container when it is inside a card?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify data table that is nested inside a v-card so that I can enable an inline search on the data table, but this is causing it to shrink down and only take up a small amount of the overall container whereas it was filling the entire container when not nested in the v-card.

I have reproduced a minimal example of this on codepen at https://codepen.io/bigtunacan/project/editor/XGRpVL

The main area of concern though is here.

```
      <v-list-tile @click="">
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>dashboard</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>Dashboard</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>

      <v-list-tile @click="">
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>Settings</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>

    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>

  <v-toolbar app fixed clipped-left>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Candy Bars</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-toolbar>

  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid fill-height>

    <template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          Routes
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-text-field append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details v-model="search"></v-text-field>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers" :items="routes" :search="search" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'route', params: {id: props.item.id}}">{{ props.item.name }}</router-link></td>
            <td>{{ props.item.agency }}</td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-card>
    </template>

    </v-container>
  </v-content>

  <v-footer app fixed>
    <span>&copy; 2017</span>
  </v-footer>

</v-app>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of the `<template>`, wrap the card in a `<v-layout child-flex>` like so:

```
...
<v-content>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>

    <v-layout child-flex>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          ...
```

`child-flex` is a class that gives its children (in this case just the card) the css rule `flex: 1 1 auto`, making them grow to fill available space.

Comment: This helped fix an overflow-x of a v-datatable inside a card. Thank you!

Comment: That worked but couldn't find `child-flex` in the official documentation as of Vuetify 1.5.13

Comment: this is apparently a hidden feature in the v-layout api https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-layout/

Answer (score 2):

add the property `width="100vw"` to the `v-card` element

```
<v-container fluid fill-height>
  <v-card width="100vw">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    />
  </v-card>
</v-container>
```

based on the OP's example (a little) and the current version of vuetify (v2.3.19),